# How to reference string resources from another resource in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

In my application, there is some "keyword" that appears quite often and spread in the entire application. I want to have a single instance of it, so when I need to change it I don't need to go through the entire resource file and change it one by one.

For example, I would want to do something like this:

```
<data name="Foo" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Foo</value>
</data>

<data name="ReferenceFoo" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>{Foo} is the best, {Foo} is the future</value>
</data>
```

Is there a way to achieve this, or is there any other way to achieve similar effect?

Comment: Do as you've wrote, preprocess the data. You can preprocess offline when you compiling the app, or online when your app loads assets, both methods have pros and cons.

Comment: If you make that a resource set in a resource dictionary and merge it in app.xaml you can bind or reference it. You can over-write it valueApplication.Current.Resources["SomeKey"] = new object; Make it implement inotifypropertychanged and you can bind  value, set that in code. Since it;s a resource you can also override with another instance merged in at a more local scope than application - window.resources or panel.resources etc.

Comment: There is no string concatenation available in XAML but you may of course create your resources programmatically.

Comment: You could add a placeholder to an uncompiled xaml file and pre process that. This is a "replace all kind" of a deal changing any instance of say "%%%%" to a (new) fixed string. You could dynamically xamlreader.load such a file as a resource dictionary and merge into resources at run time.

Comment: Thanks for the advise, I think our application is not so big that the overhead of pre-processing the xaml will be worthy.

Comment: Still I am a bit shocked that this feature is not there, I feel like it seems to be a rather common thing that could come in handy!

Comment: @Noobnewbier: XAML is a *markup* language.

Comment: @mm8 I am aware that it is a markup language, however I am unsure what is the implication and how would it contradict with my statement.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating a bit more?

Comment: @Noobnewbier: Please refer to my previous comment.

Comment: @mm8 unfortunately, I am unable to see what exactly are you referring to.

Comment: do you mind explaining it a bit more, or alternatively provide an answer if that's easier?

Comment: @Noobnewbier: There is no string concatenation available in XAML but you may of course create your resources programmatically.